# (Alternatives to) Filtering/Slicing an Array with a boolean mask in numba

Tags: python, numpy, filtering, numba

Im trying to accelerate the slicing/filtering of a numpy array with numba.
My array has this shape (35999405, 6) and it takes about 0.3s to resize/filter it without numba:

```
def optfilt_with_mask(arr, column, filt):
    return(arr[arr[:, column] == filt, 4])
```

I've tried to use numba to accelerate it:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def optfilt_with_mask( column: numba.int32 , filt: numba.int32, arr: numba.types.Array('<U9',2,'A')) -> numba.types.Array('<U9',1,'A'):
    return(arr[arr[:, column] == str(filt), 4])

for ind in inds: #loop over 1.7 million elements
    filt_arr = optfilt_with_mask(0, conf, array)
```

But apparently numba does not support operations of that kind:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(array([unichr x 9], 2d, F), Tuple(Literal[bool](False), Literal[int](4)))
```

How can I make this work with numba? And is it even worth a try or is it just faster to do the slice like I did above?

Comment: If you have an array of unicode string, then Numba is not the right too. String are very slow in Numba and developers only provide a minimal support for strings just for convenience, not performance. Numba is meant to be used for numerical computations in the first place. Besides, unicode strings tends to be slow compared to ASCII based operations in practice. If you can, please use ASCII instead. Moreover, many advanced features of Numpy are not supported in Numba but this is not much an issue since you can generally use bsaic loops (which are fast in Numba and the standard way to do this).

Comment: By the way, `arr[:, column]` is certainly not cache-efficient (Numpy arrays are generally row-major so accessing the last dimension contiguously is faster).

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for the answer. So to summarize I should convert my strings to ASCII notation and rewrite `arr[arr[:, column] == str(filt), 4]` as loops or should I just optimize my numpy notation and skip numba alltogether because numba is not meant for filtering arrays. Or is there a third better option to reduce those 0.3s?

Comment: You can try ASCII + a loop, but you may still encounter some issue with Numba. It should worth trying. Regarding performance, caching is critical here as mentioned earlier. I do not know what is the strides of `arr` but if the array is row-major and there are several columns, then you will waste >85% of the memory bandwidth (possibly >90% on Intel CPUs). Wasting such bandwidth can make the code far slower if it is memory bound. Numba cannot solve this alone (nor Numpy). If so, you need to transpose the array.

Comment: What are the data characteristics of `arr`? Is it sorted on `column`? For your `(35999405, 6)`, how many matches are output?